# Move back VS Step back

Tags: grammar

He was standing close to the TV.

> "Move back from the TV."
>
> "Step back from the TV."

Do they have different meaning?

Comment: I'm curious, do "step" and "move" mean the same in your native language?
 If I were to ask you to "take a step forward" or  "move forward" you would consider the meanings to be identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have the same meaning except that "step" specifies that the movement back is by stepping (rather than crawling, rolling etc.) and may also imply that the distance back required is only a single step.

Answer (score 1):

Move back sounds more physical, while "step back" or, more commonly, "step away" has a metaphorical meaning of putting a mental or emotional distance between ones self and something.

Answer (score -1):

I have the proof of oxford dictionary as well as the famous book of strategic learning which conclude that both terms are same, please refer to below link.

oxford dictionary-
https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-spanish/step_back?locale=en

the famous book was written by margaret sutherland 
https://books.google.co.in/books?id=91Tg819qO_sC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=Move+back+VS+Step+back&source=bl&ots=PgpTtvIiBj&sig=kazABaoTPWaGiBOgit6VuCKLVW0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHq_vT6b_WAhXIOI8KHZWyBrY4WhDoAQhOMAY#v=onepage&q=Move%20back%20VS%20Step%20back&f=false

step back
dar un paso atrás, v.
PHRASAL VERB

1
(move back) dar un paso atrás
(move back) retroceder
to step back (from sth) — distanciarse (de algo)